# "Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue, data-quality

I have this code, but I get the "Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'".

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    columns =["facturar","imptoretenido","crossborder","moneda","depositar","estado","facturaid","saldoinicial","unidades","fecha","iva","send","saldofinal","incluirtransferencia","fechadeposito","userid","id","DataQualityRulesPass","DataQualityRulesFail","DataQualityRulesSkip","DataQualityEvaluationResult"]
    
    # Selecciona las columnas.
    dfc = dfc.select(columns)
    
    # Convierte las columnas de arreglo de string a string.
    for column in columns:
        if dfc[column].dataType == "array<string>":
            dfc = dfc.withColumn(column, dfc[column].cast("string"))
    
    return dfc
```

why I get this error and how can I fix it?